# Запятая перед КАК

Tags: как, пунктуация

Нужно ли в предложении выделять запятыми *как родителей*?

> Акция призвана проинформировать вас
> как родителей об увлечениях детей.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фраза, действительно, канцелярская. Но если уж так получилось, нужно прояснить пунктуацию.

Я думаю, обособление нужно, т.к. приложение имеет значение причины - "так как вы являетесь родителями", а не "в качестве родителей".

Акция призвана проинформировать вас, как родителей, об увлечениях детей.

Может, это всё-таки не акция, а мероприятие? Акция - это действие, когда вы совместно с кем-то что-то делаете для кого-то: акция "Чистый берег", акция "Аллея в честь Героев" и др. А у вас классный час, вероятно? Или всё-таки акция?

Comment: Пример из Розенталя:
*Я говорю как литератор* (не "в качестве литератора", а "так как являюсь литератором").

Comment: Это не тот пример, здесь приложение с союзом как характеризует предмет с какой-то стороны, запятой нет. в заданной фразе нет характеристики, родителям не напоминают, что они должны иметь качества родителей, а пытаются показать важность мероприятия, потому что им это необходимо знать, так как они являются родителями. Фраза Розенталя выглядела бы так:Я ,как литератор , говорю правильно...

Comment: К тому же относится к личному местоимению - ещё повод обособить

Comment: Я сначала тоже так думала, но мне показалось, что здесь выступают родители в качестве. Вы - это родители

Comment: Вот если бы было так: Вы прищли сюда как родители - это в качестве, запятой нет,а в заданном предложении именно причина - зап. нужны.

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно, но фраза удивительно корявая. Не говорят так по-русски! А нельзя: "проинформировать родителей об увлечениях детей"? Или: "проинформировать вас об увлечениях ваших детей"?

Все равно плохо: "призвана проинформировать" — за каким чертом нужен такой книжно-канцелярский стиль?

Интересно, что это за "акция" такая, без которой родители не узнают об увлечениях своих детей...

Comment: спасибо, я воспользуюсь вашим советом

Comment: @Верьясова Если ответ помог - отметьте его галочкой. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Таинственная фраза. Всё дело в том, о каких детях идет речь.

1) Если о детях вообще (не о ваших детях), а собственные дети у вас тоже есть, то это значение "в качестве", оборот не обособляется:

Акция призвана проинформировать вас как родителей об увлечениях детей.

2) Если речь идет о ваших детях, то  здесь значение причин  вне конкуренции (обособление оборота). По отношению к вашим детям вы **только родитель**, другого качества просто нет. А если его нет, то какой смысл его называть:

Акция призвана проинформировать вас, как родителей, об увлечениях (ваших) детей.